# jGrasp - System.out.println not showing even though code is successful

Tags: java, system.out, jgrasp

I'm making this java file for a class, but when I use the test runner and complete the operation, the System.out.println() doesn't come up at all in the console. The console says that the operation was completed successfully but nothing is coming up.

```
public class ShapeMetrics {
    public static float getAreaOfRectangle(float width, float height) {
        float area = width * height;
        return area;
     }
}
```

```
public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String args[]){

      float w = 6.1F;
      float h = 3.3F;
      float area = ShapeMetrics.getAreaOfRectangle (w, h);
      System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: " + area);
      System.out.print("test");
   }

}
```

Comment: What command are you using to run the test tunner?

Comment: I'm pretty new at this but I've been pressing the green plus sign called compile file on jGrasp

Comment: Wait I think I figured it out, thank you though!

Comment: Would you like to post your solution as an answer. It might help someone if they stumble on this thread in future.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the OP was just compiling the code, not actually running it.